# Why does f(a)=g(a)=0 in this proof of L'Hôpital's rule?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation

I saw this proof of L'Hôpital's rule in Thomas' calculus: Early transcendentals (14th ed., pg.261).

From Cauchy's mean value theorem:

Suppose functions ƒ and g are continuous on $[a, b]$ and differentiable throughout
$(a, b)$, $g′(x) ≠ 0$ throughout $(a, b)$ and suppose that $x$ lies to the right of $a$, and lies within the interval $[a,b]$.
Let
$ \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}= \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{g(x)-g(a)}$

Since $f(a)=g(a)=0$ then

$ \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}= \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$

I understand the rest of the proof from this point onwards, however I do not understand where $f(a)=g(a)=0$ comes from, as this was not mentioned as part of Cauchy's mean value theorem, nor in L'Hopitals. I am probably overthinking it as it was clearly too trivial to expound upon in any detail, but I do not see how it can easily be inferred.

Comment: It should be one of the assumptions in the statement of L'Hospital's rule.  What is the statement?

Comment: The proof is for the case when you're trying to evaluate $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ and $f(a) = g(a) = 0$, so you end up with the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ if you try to plug $x = a$ into the argument of the limit. That's why you're using L'Hopital's rule to begin with.

Comment: @NateEldredge Oh my bad I just checked again and it is mentioned. But I think my question still stands as to what the justification of the assumption is, and why it still works when f(a) does not equal g(a)

Comment: It's just the precise statement of the concept that (this version of) L'Hospital's rule only applies to limits of the form $\frac{0}{0}$.  If $f(a)$ and $g(a)$ are not both zero then the limit is not of this form, so we should not expect L'Hospital to work.

Comment: @NateEldredge But does it not also apply to limits of $\infty/\infty$

Comment: This particular version does not apply to $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.  You would need to prove that separately (e.g. by writing $\frac{f}{g} = \frac{1/g}{1/f}$).  The author may have left this as an exercise.

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah I see I think I understand now thank you